# Modbus 485 Communication In Case of 2 or more Masters/Clients

Tags: modbus, serial-communication, rs485, modbus-tcp

I am curruntly working on building industrial application. I have a Slave - PCB device built on STM32 that gets data from the sensors. It transfers serial data in every 5 seconds through RS485 USB Converter to the Master A, according to the Master A's request. Now, I want to add another Master B using  RS485 Converter to LAN. In this case, how can I avoid data corruption or collisions when both masters try to read data simultanously.

[***A PCB Slave includes Modbus RS485 library which means it sends serial data.]

RS485 Converter to LAN (Converter that I am using) ->
[http://www.realsys.co.kr/goods/content.asp?guid=581&cate=367&params=cate=367^sword=^swhat=^listsort=favorite^listtype=album^listsize=5^page=](http://www.realsys.co.kr/goods/content.asp?guid=581&cate=367&params=cate=367%5Esword=%5Eswhat=%5Elistsort=favorite%5Elisttype=album%5Elistsize=5%5Epage=)

More clearly, I want to read data from PCB Slave using two masters. One is using RS485 RTU USB Converter and the other one is using RS485 Converter to TCP/IP. Is it possible to communicate smoothly in this scenario without interruptions or data corruption?

**WHY I need to use 2 Masters:**
Because, we have already built the product using Master A (using USB Converter). It is already installed on the places. Now, some customers want to get the same product plus, the option for Master B (Modbus TCP/IP). By using Master B, they want to get sensors data to their own industrial PC using LAN.

I have set hardware parts and used some logic to test the case.
When both masters tried to read data at the same time I am getting *Timeout Error* from the Master that uses USB Converter. The other Master is throwing the following *Exception error*:

```
Exception - System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the 
transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a 
call to WSACancelBlockingCall. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A blocking operation was 
interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, 
Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 
offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 
offset, Int32 size)
at FluentModbus.ModbusTcpClient.TransceiveFrame(Byte 
unitIdentifier, ModbusFunctionCode functionCode, Action`1 
extendFrame)in 
/home/runner/work/FluentModbus/FluentModbus/src/FluentModbus/Client/ModbusTcpClient.cs:line 269
   at FluentModbus.ModbusClient.ReadInputRegisters(Byte unitIdentifier, UInt16 startingAddress, UInt16 quantity) in /home/runner/work/FluentModbus/FluentModbus/src/FluentModbus/Client/ModbusClient.cs:line 317
   at FluentModbus.ModbusClient.ReadInputRegisters[T](Int32 unitIdentifier, Int32 startingAddress, Int32 count)
```

Comment: why do you have two masters reading the same data? use one that publishes the data from somewhere where you can read it as much and as often as you want. otherwise, you'll probably have to consider synchronization between different masters.

Comment: the approach is wrong. you don't want to have two masters reading the same data at the same time. they must be synchronized so they don't read at the same time. however, this will result in different data being obtained in the serial masters.

Comment: The [spec](https://modbus.org/docs/Modbus_over_serial_line_V1_02.pdf) states "Only one master (at the same time) is connected to the bus, and one
or several (247 maximum number) slaves nodes are also connected to the same serial bus". So what you are trying to do is no longer really Modbus (unless you can coordinate your masters such that only one is connected at a time).

Answer (score 0):

You can't put multiple masters on a serial line. You need a different hardware setup where you put a Modbus TCP to RS485 Gateway (not a dumb serial to ethernet converter) in front of the serial line, and then both masters need to use Modbus TCP to talk to the Gateway.

[image]

Comment: According to this diagram, can a Slave recognize a Master? Or even it is the case should I aslo consider synchronization to avoid data collisions?